# what is the best approach to handle promises with chai-as-promised?

Tags: protractor, mocha.js, chai, chai-as-promised

I just want to know that whether this approach is good or not while using chai-as-promised with mocha and protractor?

```
let options = customers.all(by.tagName('option'));
           options.then(function (items){
                for(let i=0 ; i<items.length ; i++){
                        items[i].getText().then(function(txt:any){
                            if(txt == "ABC XYZ"){
                                items[i].click();
                            }
                        })
                }
            });
```

Comment: Chai-as-Promised is extension to chai which is assertion library.  What you are trying to do is to solve promises using chai-as-promised and it is not the way to do it.  ECMA script 2017 support async/await which is best way to get rid of promises. You can use it then there would not be need of chai-as-promised libray.

Comment: @NitinSahu I am new to testing and currently very confused. I just wanted to know that can we do that whole thing like "options.to.eventually" syntax if yes then please tell me how. or else we should be handling promises with async/await then whats the use of chai-as-promised?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should learn more about chai plugin chai-as-promise. Visit [This url](https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/chai-as-promised/) to know more about this plugin.

Second you need to understand that this plugin is meant for handling assertion statement that has dependency on some promise. It is not meant for dealing all the promises. If you are new then you should learn using async/await with protractor.
Refer this post for more details
[first source](https://www.protractortest.org/#/async-await)
[second source](https://medium.com/@anandujjwal/end-to-end-testing-using-protractor-with-async-await-46dc11d948d0)